# Get the ID of clicked button only in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

In the snippet bellow, if you click one of the buttons, then all three buttons will re-act and rotate with the clicked one.

How can I rotate only the clicked one? I tried to pass unique id of each button to `rotate()` function, but all what I tried have failed.

And if there is one rotated (active) button, how can I make sure that the others are not rotated (not active)?

```js
angular.module("myApp", ["ngAnimate"])
.controller("main", function($scope){ 
   $scope.isActive = false;
        $scope.rotate = function () {
            $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
        };
})
```

```css
.rotate,
    .rotateCounterwise {
        -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
        -moz-transition: 300ms ease all;
        -o-transition: 300ms ease all;
        transition: 300ms ease all;
    }
    .rotate {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
    .rotateCounterwise {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular-animate.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="main">
  <button  ng-click="rotate()"
           ng-animate="{enter: 'rotate', leave: 'rotateCounterwise'}"
           ng-class="{true: 'rotate', false: 'rotateCounterwise'}[isActive]"
           style="cursor:pointer; border: 2px solid; border-radius: 17%;">
                Click
  </button>
  <button  ng-click="rotate()"
           ng-animate="{enter: 'rotate', leave: 'rotateCounterwise'}"
           ng-class="{true: 'rotate', false: 'rotateCounterwise'}[isActive]"
           style="cursor:pointer; border: 2px solid; border-radius: 17%;">
                Click
  </button>
  <button  ng-click="rotate()"
           ng-animate="{enter: 'rotate', leave: 'rotateCounterwise'}"
           ng-class="{true: 'rotate', false: 'rotateCounterwise'}[isActive]"
           style="cursor:pointer; border: 2px solid; border-radius: 17%;">
           Click
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Well you get `ng-click="rotate($event)"`the target...but if that helps I don't know. maybe you could pass in an id... or set one yourself `<button id="">`...but then we are again at $event.target

Comment: I tried that, and I get the clicked button id, but then I didn't know how to process and use it with `isActive` model to opposite its status (rotate to un-rotate) @Daniel

Comment: yes. right. Well I had something similar ...and I used an array to do that. `isActive[0]` ...something like that....a bit tedious but the easiest solution i came up with

Comment: @HalaElBarchah try my solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternate way to define three different flags

```js
angular.module("myApp", ["ngAnimate"])
.controller("main", function($scope){ 
   $scope.isActive = false;
})
```

```css
.rotate,
    .rotateCounterwise {
        -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
        -moz-transition: 300ms ease all;
        -o-transition: 300ms ease all;
        transition: 300ms ease all;
    }
    .rotate {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
    .rotateCounterwise {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular-animate.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="main">
  <button  ng-click="isActive=!isActive;isActive1=false; isActive2=false; "
           ng-animate="{enter: 'rotate', leave: 'rotateCounterwise'}"
           ng-class="{true: 'rotate', false: 'rotateCounterwise'}[isActive]"
           style="cursor:pointer; border: 2px solid; border-radius: 17%;">
                Click
  </button>
  <button  ng-click="isActive1=!isActive1; isActive=false;isActive2=false;"
           ng-animate="{enter: 'rotate', leave: 'rotateCounterwise'}"
           ng-class="{true: 'rotate', false: 'rotateCounterwise'}[isActive1]"
           style="cursor:pointer; border: 2px solid; border-radius: 17%;">
                Click
  </button>
  <button  ng-click="isActive2=!isActive2; isActive=false;isActive1=false;"
           ng-animate="{enter: 'rotate', leave: 'rotateCounterwise'}"
           ng-class="{true: 'rotate', false: 'rotateCounterwise'}[isActive2]"
           style="cursor:pointer; border: 2px solid; border-radius: 17%;">
           Click
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, that's an appropriate way to solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want, thank you. can you solve the second part of the question? `And if there is one rotated (active) button, how can I make sure that the others are not rotated (not active)?`

Comment: @HalaElBarchah I've edited my answer, now if you click on any button other will get (not active), if they were (active).

Comment: @HalaElBarchah Your welcome, Great to see that it's working for you :)

Comment: could be a "current" flag... first button: current=0, second button, current = 1... and the class tests for current == 0, for example

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard coding each button element you can define a list of button objects in your controller, where each object has a `isActive` flag. You can then use `ng-repeat` to create each of the button elements.

**Example**

```
$scope.buttons = [
 {
   text: 'Click',
   isActive: false
 },
 {
   text: 'Click2',
   isActive: false
 },
 {
   text: 'Click3',
   isActive: false
 }
]
```

Now each button can be identified by an index in the array and passed into the `$scope.rotate` function.

```
<button 
   ng-repeat="button in buttons track by $index"
   ng-click="rotate($index)"
   ...
</button>
```

And then you can update the `$scope.rotate` function to toggle the `isActive` flag to the button object by using the passed in index parameter.

```
$scope.rotate = function (index) {
   $scope.buttons[index].isActive = !$scope.buttons[index].isActive;
};
```

To toggle the actual css class you use the `button.isActive` field like so:

```
<button
   ...
   ng-class="{true: 'rotate', false: 'rotateCounterwise'}[button.isActive]"
</button>
```

Updated your snippet, but here's a jsbin example too: http://jsbin.com/vajolokifa/edit?html,css,js,output

```js
angular.module("myApp", ["ngAnimate"])
.controller("main", function($scope){
  
   $scope.buttons = [
     {
       text: 'Click',
       isActive: false
     },
     {
       text: 'Click2',
       isActive: false
     },
     {
       text: 'Click3',
       isActive: false
     }
   ];
   
   $scope.rotate = function (index) {
      $scope.buttons[index].isActive = !$scope.buttons[index].isActive;
   };
})
```

```css
.rotate,
    .rotateCounterwise {
        -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
        -moz-transition: 300ms ease all;
        -o-transition: 300ms ease all;
        transition: 300ms ease all;
    }
    .rotate {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
    .rotateCounterwise {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="main">
  
  <button  ng-repeat="button in buttons track by $index"
           ng-click="rotate($index)"
           ng-animate="{enter: 'rotate', leave: 'rotateCounterwise'}"
           ng-class="{true: 'rotate', false: 'rotateCounterwise'}[button.isActive]"
           style="cursor:pointer; border: 2px solid; border-radius: 17%;">
           {{button.text}}
  </button>
  
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, I can't use `ng-repeat` because there are lots of elements between the buttons. let's say I have to write each button manually, so I can assign id to each one, but how can I pass this id to the function `rotate()` and use it~